# Probability distribution of the standard deviation of a gamma distribution

Tags: distributions, simulation, hierarchical-bayesian

I want to generate some data using a series of Gamma distributions in a Bayesian hierarchical setting.

I need to generate the data for a series of contexts, but I got only 2 data points per context, which represent the means of the context data I want to generate. Specifically, I have a mean waiting time per context and I want to generate individuals' waiting times that would produce such mean.

These gamma distributions are parametrized with their mean and SD, transformed in shape ($(\mu/SD)^2$) and scale ($SD^2/\mu$) parameters.

I can simulate the mean parameter distribution for a context using its characteristics (bayesian regression predictive distribution) but I don't have any way to generate an SD distribution for a specific context. Therefore I thought of using the SD of the predictive distribution of the mean (little bit of a hack, not having data on individuals; if you got better solutions, feel free to suggest). But this parameter would be 1 value for each context, while I would like to have a multivariate distribution of means and SDs for each context, to increase variability. Of course, I will have to decide arbitrarily the scale of the SD distribution.

Reading around I understood that both Gamma and Chisquare distribution can model the PDF of an SD. but I didn't understand which one should be used, in which case and how.

Comment: I am not sure I follow the question, The standard deviation of a gamma population is a fixed number, not a variable.

Comment: Do you mean the standard deviation estimate$$\sqrt{[(x_1-\bar x_n)^2+\cdots+(x_n-\bar x_n)^2]/[n-1]}$$?

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what you've got (what do you mean by 'sample of means'?), what you want, and what your purpose is. // Are you interested in making CIs for population mean, variance, SD, shape parameter, scale parameter, rate parameter? // _Please edit Question;_ not everybody reads comments.

Comment: To everyone, I meant in a hierarchical bayesian setting, that is parameters are random variables with a distribution